# Dumping data from website's Database

Tags: datatypes, database-size, database-link

I'm looking for ways to browse and dump the database of a particular content from the website. To be more specific i am collecting the database of the Skills designed for the device amazon alexa. Is there any way where i can access the database of all the updated skills list without browsing one by one and copying each skill to create a list? Thanks and regards, EJ

Answer (score 0):

This has 0 to do with databases.

> collecting the database of the Skills

Sure, but you're really just crawling their API. Find the web portal: https://www.amazon.com/b?node=13727921011

From there you'll see `b?node=` in the url. I searched for `node=` in the api. I [found this](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_ListMatchingProducts.html) in the passage,

- ProductCategoryId Identifier for a product category (or browse node).
- ProductCategoryName   Name of a product category (or browse node).

Knowing that the term here is `browse node`. I set out googling for a newer API than the MarketPlace Web Services (Amazon MWS) which was last updated in 2011. I found the "Product Advertising API" which was last updated in 2013. BTW, this is normal for Amazon. Their docs are crap, so move fast through them.

The Product Advertising API supports a method called [ItemSearch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html) which supports a `BrowseNode` argument which does exactly what you want. You'll have to crawl through that because it only returns 10 results per page.

Working with Amazon is a blast. Godspeed. Cache the data with a `time_crawled_idx`, and `time_crawled_detail`. You'll only get the ASIN from that. From there, off to [`ItemLookup`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html)

If you're looking to spec out the project, be glad to help contact info in profile.